# Mulit module with each module provide rest service in gradle with spring

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I am try to create multi module spring project with **Gradle**. 
Each module has independent rest api service.

I haven't idea too much with **Gradle**. 
**library-application** can access by **application** module but not able to execute simultaneously API of each modules using tomcat.

**Module 1st : application**

File **settings.gradle:**

```
 rootProject.name = 'application'

 include ':library-application'
 project(':library-application').projectDir = new File('../library-application')
```

File **build.gradle:**

```
    buildscript {
        ext { springBootVersion = '2.1.3.RELEASE' }
        repositories {      jcenter()
                    mavenCentral()
                    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }   
            }
        dependencies {  classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
                classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-tomcat-plugin:1.0',
                classpath 'org.apache.openjpa:openjpa-all:2.4.1'
                classpath 'at.schmutterer.oss.gradle:gradle-openjpa:0.2.0'
             }
    }

    plugins {
        id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.5.RELEASE"
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    apply plugin: 'war'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'tomcat'
    bootJar {
        baseName = 'gs-multi-application'
        version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories { mavenCentral() }

    dependencies {
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
        compile project(':library-application')
        testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    }
```

**Module 2nd : library-application**
File **build.gradle:**

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {      jcenter()
                    mavenCentral()
                    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }   
            }
        dependencies {  classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
                classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-tomcat-plugin:1.0',
                classpath 'org.apache.openjpa:openjpa-all:2.4.1'
                classpath 'at.schmutterer.oss.gradle:gradle-openjpa:0.2.0'
             }
    }

    plugins {
        id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.5.RELEASE"
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    apply plugin: 'war'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'tomcat'

    plugins { id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.5.RELEASE" }

    ext { springBootVersion = '2.1.3.RELEASE' }

    jar {
        baseName = 'gs-multi-library'
        version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories { mavenCentral() }

    dependencies {
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
        testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean: "not able to execute simultaneously API"? How do you start your Spring Boot application, embedded or container?

Comment: I want run root project "application", its child "library-application" should run own webservice.

Comment: It's not the way how Gralde child project works. You should consider the root project as kind of "shared library" and it shouldn't be "run" in general.

Comment: That means, Is it not possible server start from root project and individual project give service separate webservices?

Answer (score 0):

In general, root project in Gradle does nothing but only hold a overall `build.gradle` and `settings.properties` to group child projects together. Module planning should be done via managing dependencies of child projects, not the folder structure.

Try to organize your projects in this way:

```
root_project (very simple project doing nothing)
  - library-application
    - Provide service controllers
  - application (depends on library-application)
    - Provide SpringBootApplication
```